# Are there any pre-20th century examples of an augmented 6th chord with a leading tone?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, harmony

In a discussion about blues music, a friend described the presence of both minor and major thirds in a dominant-seventh tonality as a blues innovation.  I wondered if there were examples of dissonant non-chord tones in pre-20th century music that give this effect?  The context that popped into my head was an augmented 6th chord (enharmonically equivalent to a dominant seventh) with a leading tone in the melody resolving to the tonic.  The leading tone would function as the minor third, against the major third in the augmented 6th.  But I couldn't think of any specific examples in pre-20th century music where this actually happens.  Can anyone think of such an example?

Comment: The usual German augmented 6th (enharmonically equivalent to a dominant 7th harmony) contains scale degrees 6, 1, 3, and ♯4 of the minor key. It typically resolves to V, with the 6 and ♯4 expanding to the octave. It does not include scale degree (♯)7, the leading tone of the key. What do you mean by "the leading tone would function as the minor third"?

Comment: Agreed with Remy here, you’re notes don’t add up. Also, augmented 6th chords usually lead us somewhere, serving more as a pivot. It sounds like you and your friend were more discussing modal mixture.

Answer (score 3):

I think OP's question makes sense; they're asking about a minor third (well, an augmented second) above the bass note of the augmented sixth.

In C, an augmented sixth is A♭, C, and F♯. This is shown below in the "A" example.

[image]

But along with the C, I think OP is asking about also including a B, an augmented second ("minor third") above the bass A♭; this is shown above in the "B" example.

---

Now, regarding the actual question, I can't think of any examples that include both of these scale degrees.

However, while most augmented sixth chords function as pre-dominants, there are augmented sixths chords that function as dominants. One is shown below; note that the asterisked chord includes the augmented sixth from D♭ to B, and the chord is equivalent to a French augmented sixth chord. But note that this chord resolves to a tonic of C, not a dominant in F.

[image]

Whether or not this is a *bona fide* augmented sixth is up for discussion. Often it's just a V43 that then changes to a lowered scale-degree 2 before moving to tonic, but the point here is that **this augmented sixth chord does include the leading tone**. This is exactly how [Bruckner used it in the Adagio of his Seventh Symphony](https://youtu.be/T-4JuDCoq4g?t=4m10s), written in the early 1880s (I start the video at the overall progression, but the chord is at 4:20):

[image]

Comment: You're correct about my original intent - I was looking for something exactly like the 'B' example you described.  Or really, anything with the same intervallic relationships - a chord with a minor third (or augmented second) above the root clashing against a major third, with a minor seventh (or augmented sixth) also.  I see how your Bruckner example involves a leading tone in an augmented sixth chord, but it doesn't involve the "clashing thirds" that I am hoping to find.

Comment: I'm not sure how much luck you'll have looking for clashing thirds this early. But I'll keep thinking about it!

Comment: [Clashing thirds](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/can-a-chord-contain-both-the-c-and-c%e2%99%af-notes-as-opposed-to-containing-c-and-d/65933) aren't all that hard to find. The combo of clashing thirds and an augmented 6th above the root is a taller order, I think.